Blazor SSR Google ReCAPTCHA
I'm using a static Blazor SSR project with Google ReCAPTCHA Enterprise. The ReCAPTCHA uses a checkbox. The implementation would be to add the following script to a page like the following example:
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
<div class="container-fluid">
     <section class="container-lg py-3">
         <h3 class="text-center">Contacta con nosotros</h3>
         <p class="text-center">Envienos un correo y nos pondremos en contacto con usted.</p>
         <EmailForm/>
     </section> 
</div> 
<HeadContent>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js" async defer></script> </HeadContent>

The <EmailForm/> component is a form like the following:
<EditForm Enhance Model="ContactEmail" OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmitAsync" FormName="contactForm">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
            <CustomValidation @ref="_customValidator"/>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Nombre:</label>
                <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@ContactEmail.Name"/>
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ContactEmail.Name)"/>
            </div>

            ... more code ...

            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="@SiteKey"]" data-action="@DataAction"></div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
        </EditForm>

Getting a result as can be seen in the following image:
Page with expected ReCAPTCHA
When you change pages and return to the form page, the ReCAPTCHA disappears and does not reappear unless the page is reloaded again.
Page not showing ReCAPTCHA
What is the reason for the ReCAPTCHA to disappear and not reappear? or how can I make it reappear?
What is desired is that the ReCAPTCHA always appears.

I had the same issue implementing Cloudflare's Turnstile, the trick is to add the data-permanent attribute to the container.
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="@SiteKey" data-action="@DataAction" data-permanent></div>


Blazor's enhanced navigation and form handing may undo dynamic changes to the DOM if the updated content isn't part of the server rendering. To preserve the content of an element, use the data-permanent attribute.

You could also reinitialise recaptcha from the enhancedLoad event:
Blazor.addEventListener('enhancedload', () => console.log('Enhanced update!'));

I also encountered problems when refreshing the page with deferring loading of the Cloudflare script, remove this from the script tag.
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js"></script>

MS docs - Enhanced navigation and form handling

With the "data-permanent" I managed to keep the ReCAPTCHA from disappearing. I don't understand what you mean about the 
Remove “defer” from the recaptcha script tag.
